# How to unit test a method in angular which creates object of imported class

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am unit testing an angular component using jasmine and karma. Comonent has a method which creates new object of an imported class and call one of its member function. How should I write unit test case for following scenario.

Relevant code of `myapp.component.ts`

```
import { pdfctrls } from '../path/to/pdfctrl';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapp',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.css']
})
export class MyappComponent {
  obj: any;

  // other variables and method 

  // this method needs to be unit tested
  downloadPdf() {
    const pdf: pdfctrls = new pdfctrls(this.obj);
    pdf.getPdfData('filename');
  }

  // rest of the methods
}
```

Relevant code of `pdfctrl.ts`

```
export class pdfctrls {
  obj: any;

  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj= obj;
  }

  getPdfData = function (params) {
    // method implementation
  }

  // rest of the methods
```

I have tried to spy on `pdfctrl` class but it didn't worked. Solution which makes least changes in `myapp.component.ts` is preferred.

Comment: You can not spy on objects that are instanced in your main method. To do this, you must to inject that object by dependency. Then you can declare a provider using a mock.

Comment: @Alan I can't make changes to code now. Is there any workaround to test this code ?

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal Please mark it as an answer if it helped. It'll help others also looking for similar question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so there are 2 ways:

1. You change the code and inject a service `PdfCtrls` , that would help you mock . As suggested by @Alan, that's the only way to mock.
2. Or as a workaround with "**least change**" which you have asked, you can do:

```
import { pdfctrls } from '../path/to/pdfctrl';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapp',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.css']
})
export class MyappComponent {
  obj: any;
  pdf: pdfctrls; // <------- CREATE IT AT COMPONENT LEVEL
  // other variables and method 

  // this method needs to be unit tested
  downloadPdf() {
    this.pdf = new pdfctrls(this.obj);
    this.pdf.getPdfData('filename');
  }

  // rest of the methods
}
```

in **spec.ts**

```
  it('should create pdf object on downloadPDF()', () => {
    expect(component.pdf).toBeUndefined();
    component.downloadPDF();
    expect(component.pdf).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.pdf).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
      someproperties: "someproperties"
    }));
  });
```

With this test, you can just make sure that the object has been created properly. You can't test whether `getPDFData()` was called or now.